# Basic WIndows Workflows 4 Persistance in a webserver hosted .xamlx services not working

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, sqlworkflowpersistencese

I'm trying to create a Windows Workflow 4 Service hosted in IIS.  I've configured the service as below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="ApprovalService" behaviorConfiguration="ApprovalServiceBehavior">
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ApprovalServiceBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <sqlWorkflowInstanceStore connectionStringName="WorkflowPersistence" />
                <workflowIdle timeToPersist="0" timeToUnload="0:05:0"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

The service does not persist!  There's nothing magical in the service like custom persisting of values, etc.  I've got it working in another service that does have a custom persistance method, but I can't figure out the difference.

Perhaps my service is erroring out, but I can not seem to figure out how to step into debugging either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name of your service element and the SQL connection string are correct you workflow should persist as soon as it goes idle. Did you try adding a Delay activity to ensure it goes idle or a Persist activity to force it to persist?

Try adding tracking or tracing to see what is going on. Something like

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Activities"
            switchValue="Verbose">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textListener"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="MyTraceLog.txt"
             traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: thanks @Maurice.  I believe that the project is somehow corrupt.  In a new project, I managed to get persistance to work.  However I'm still not getting the next step of my workflow to work.  The trace log shows the following (as an example.)  'System.Activities Information: 1010 : 1010Activity 'System.Activities.Statements.Sequence', DisplayName: 'Sequence', InstanceId: '4' has completed in the 'Faulted' state.dfd44601-1-129677869969456729'

Comment: ok, FINALLY got it.  was a problem with the data I was sending to the service.  The trace output helped, but what it output isn't exactly what I'd call Verbose...  Anyway, thanks again @Maurice!